# how to center h1 in navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am trying to center a text on nav bar however not successful. What am I missing

```js
// import external modules
import React, { Component } from "react";

import {
   Navbar
} from "reactstrap";
import {
   Menu
} from "react-feather";



class ThemeNavbar extends Component {
   handleClick = e => {
      this.props.toggleSidebarMenu("open");
   };
  
   render() {
      return (
         <Navbar className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-faded">
            <div className="container-fluid px-0">


<div style={{display: 'flex',  justifyContent:'center', alignItems:'center'}}>
    <h1> I am centered </h1>
</div>
               
               <div className="navbar-header">
                  <Menu
                     size={14}
                     className="navbar-toggle d-lg-none float-left"
                     onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
                     data-toggle="collapse"
                  />
                               
               </div>
            </div>
         </Navbar>
      );
   }
}


export default ThemeNavbar;
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

There is no outside CSS file that is affecting the page yet it is not working out. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Have you tried `textAlign: 'center'`?

Comment: Your snippet isn't working

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you show us a minimal, working example of your code  (your current snippet does not work run), so that we can help

Comment: add a width to the element so it can center the inner elements

Comment: This is not a React question, but an HTML/CSS question.
Maybe you could just show the resulting HTML/CSS

Answer (score 1):

I believe the rule you want to be using here is: `textAlign: 'center'`.
Assuming your `h1` doesn't have rules overriding this it should inherit it from the containing `div`. Otherwise try adding this rule to the `h1` itself.
I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<h1 style={{ textAlign: "center"}}> I am centered </h1>
```